# Some sort of number allocation algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am creating a booking system that allows a specific number of rooms/seats to be booked. Say a user can book seats/rooms numbered 1-100. My lecturer has suggested I use an algorithm that divides the reservation numbers economically so the seats left unsold are kept to a minimum. So for instance if there was 10 seats available:

User 1 books 4 seat. Given (no 1-4).
User 2 books 1 seat. Given (no 5).
User 3 books 4 seats. Given (no 6-9).
User 2 then cancels. Freeing up (no 5).
User 4 then wants to book 2 seats but the only seats available are 5 & 10 (Not together, so they do not book).

My lecturer said a common algorithm exists for this problem, but could not remember the name. I suppose it's like the algorithm used for data on a disk.

Any ideas?
Many thanks.

Comment: The same algorithms are used for implementing `malloc()` and `free()` in C.  They often use "freelists" -- linked lists of (memory) ranges that are free.  When a new request comes in, the freelist is searched for a block that is large enough to satisfy the request; there are different tradeoffs in how to choose the block (e.g. choose the first that fits, choose the smallest that fits, choose the largest) and no one policy that is everywhere optimal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no algorithm that guarantees optimality.

Take your example. To make sure you get the best setup you need to know who will cancel to make sure they are next to the free space, so that free space is continuous (and you are able to book more). Only 2 reservations can be next to the free space. Unless you can look into the future and say which of the 3 bookings will not be cancelled, you are going run a chance of making a mistake and not having optimal allocation.

You can try something similar to allocation techniques (malloc) that try to fit new booking into the smallest available space. If you have some more info about the bookings (probability it will get cancelled) you can try and make smarter choices (like double booking, as they do on the airlines). 
Failing that you could still squeeze more out of the system if you are able to reassign bookings (that's what the java garbage collector does on a major compaction).